# Rails static pages CMS engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I need simple CMS to allow non-tech folks edit some static text in app I maintaing. App is in rails 3.2 and is multilingual. What would here fit best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Refinery](http://refinerycms.com) which is now a mountable engine. Version 2.0 has been released a few days ago.

There is also a bunch of other CMS, it all depend on your needs:

- [Locomotive](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine). There is a 2.0.0.rc branch which is now a mountable engine. This looks promising with custom content type!!!
- [Comfortable Mexican Sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa) (editorial: best CMS name, ever!)
- [Browser CMS](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/browsercms)
- Radiant CMS
- and a lot more...see most of them on [Ruby-Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/browsercms)

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion is just add a WYSIWYG like CKeditor to text box. [ckeditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)

ps. rails it self can be a simple cms ... just rails g scaffold

Comment: WYSIWYG is not enought - I need also adding photos and videos with and so one, so I don't like to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

tinyMCE will allow you to do images etc, but really if you're using rails for this stuff i would (and do), use tinyMCE for text then add paperclip to add the images and video (possibly also swfupload if the videos are big).

Then you can build your template as required and pull stuff in based on the page.id or other identified.

back to multilingual:
you'll want to model up 'my_cms_item' eg. news_item and 'my_cms_item_translation' e.g. 'news_item_translation' and create a 1-Many for these so that when a user creates a news_item they can select to add additional translations in whichever language and the system just detects and pulls if available. You can make it either hide the item or default to a translation as required.

Comment: It is nice anwser, but not for my question ;)

Comment: Can you give more detail on your spec and I'll amend to suit?